# ng-repeat and ng-if to set value of td

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am trying to set td value based on condition, here is my code

```
<td>
<span ng-init="tdValue=true;"></span>
<span ng-repeat="value in data_report" ng-if="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">
<span ng-init="tdValue=false;">{{value.Completed}}</span>
</span>
<span ng-if="tdValue">0</span>
</td>
```

In the following code I am checking
1. If the condition matches set the value to value.completed
2. If not keep default value as zero

But the result i am getting is
14 0

14 is value.completes and 0 is default value (Both the values are getting printed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must target the nested `<span>`, not the repeater `<span>` itself :

```
<td>
  <span ng-init="tdValue=true"></span>
  <span ng-repeat="value in data_report">
     <span ng-if="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id" ng-init="$parent.$parent.tdValue=false">{{value.Completed}}</span>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="tdValue==true">0</span>
</td>
```

Also

- both `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` creates nested child scopes, thus `$parent.$parent` is needed to address the outer `tdValue`
- `ng-if` must consist of expressions, i.e `ng-if="tdValue == true"`

Comment: its still executing the other span with value zero and i get value as 14 0

Comment: yes, that is because if there is no value matched in fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id set to zero by default else set {{value.Completed}}. But once its executing <span ng-if="tdValue">0</span> even if tdValue is initialised to false;

Comment: Sorry it gives same result

Comment: Thanks for your time, Still the same result 14 0, Can you suggest me any link where i can get scenario like this?

Comment: @PoojaBajajDhoot Try a last time with a `$parent.$parent.tdValue=false` ... `ng-if` make a child scope as well, so you have in fact two child scopes for each iteration. I ignored that, perhaps it is really needed (but have never seen that before, `$parent` should be enough in the above, but try anyway)

Comment: @PoojaBajajDhoot, finally! Have never seen a use for $parent.$parent before, I am always using $scope variables to such things.

Comment: @davidkonrad .Great !!

Answer (score 0):

You Can use ternary operator

```
<td>
<span ng-init="tdValue=true;"></span>
<span ng-repeat="value in data_report" ng-if="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">
<span>{{tdValue==true?value.Completed:0}}</span>
</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Tried that ternary operator gives me result as 14 0 0 as its ng-repeat it will repeat as many times as the data is present

Answer (score 0):

Can you instead remove this `ng-init="tdValue=true;"` and declare it inside your controller.

> $scope.tdValue=true;

Comment: One and all gives same result 14 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td>

<span >{{selectedId}}</span>

</td>
```

This is controller code you can try out.

```
$scope.selectedId=0;
for(var i=0;i<$scope.data_report.length;i++){
if($scope.fellow.F_Id==$scope.data_report[i].fellowship_id){
$scope.selectedId=$scope.data_report[i].fellowship_id;
break;
}
}
```

Comment: This will return 14 0 0

Comment: As Ng-repeat has three sets of value so it will loop thrice. First if value matched prints 14, second value is not matched will print 0 and again third value not matched it will print 0

Comment: Hi, Where can i write this code? and will it give zero if {{selectedId}} has no value?

Comment: Yah.If id didnt get matched.it will print zero.You have to write this code inside your controller js

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to apply if condition on span tag in which you are using ng-repeat.

```
<td>
  <span ng-init="tdValue=true"></span>
  <span ng-repeat="value in data_report" ng-if="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">
     <span ng-init="$parent.$parent.tdValue=false">{{value.Completed}}</span>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="tdValue==true">0</span>
</td>
```